# How to split a string of numbers on the white space character and convert to integers

Tags: c#

I'm working on some homework and I need to get an input from the user which is a single line of numbers separated by spaces. I want to split this string and get the individual numbers out so that I can insert them into a Binary Search Tree.

I tried the split function and was able to rid of the white space but I'm not sure how to "collect" the individual numbers.

```
        string data;
        string[] newdata = { };
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a list of integers with spaces 
                           between each number.\n");
        data = Console.ReadLine();
        newdata = data.Split(null);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, newdata));
```

I want to somehow collect the elements from newdata string array and convert them into integers but I'm having a tough time figuring out how to do that.

Comment: You already found using Split ( data.Split() ) to get an array of strings. Next, use int.TryParse to try converting each array member to an integer. Discard the ones you cannot parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some smart LINQ answers are already provided, here is my *extended* step by step solution which also allows to ignore invalid numbers:

```
//Read input string
Console.Write("Input numbers separated by space: ");
string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
//Split by spaces
string[] splittedInput = inputString.Split(' ');
//Create a list to store all valid numbers
List<int> validNumbers = new List<int>();
//Iterate all splitted parts
foreach (string input in splittedInput)
{
    //Try to parse the splitted part
    if (int.TryParse(input, out int number) == true)
    {
        //Add the valid number
        validNumbers.Add(number);
    }
}
//Print all valid numbers
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", validNumbers));
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could use Linq `.Select` method combined with `.Split` method:

```
List<int> newData = data.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

If you want user to be able to enter empty spaces we need to trim the resulting strings after split. For that we can use another overload of `string.Split` method that accepts `StringSplitOptions` :

```
List<int> newData = data.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Finally if you want to allow user to enter incorrect data at times and still get collection of valid ints you could use `int.TryParse` and filter out values that were parsed incorrectly:

```
List<int> newData = data.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(s => int.TryParse(s.Trim(), out var n) ? (int?)n : null)
                        .Where(x => x != null)
                        .Select(i => i.Value)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: And if the user entered `1 23 42 Banana 45`?

Comment: It's already covered by TryParse method which will select null if false and later where condition.

Comment: @LukaszBalazy, it was later edited to use TryParse. FWIW, it should be TryParse from the beginning, and trimming is an unnecessary step.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Well, it shouldn't. The OP didn't specify that he is expecting invalid inputs... He just wanted to get numbers from string

Comment: Do you really need OP to specify that when OP says input is with ReadLine. That is what should be expected naturally, no?

Comment: @CetinBasoz It depends on specific scenario the OP is working with. Sometimes an expected behavior for such app would be to throw an exception for invalid input... But I would use tryparse in most of cases of course

Answer (score 3):

OK as code:

```
var words = data.Split();
int i;
List<int> integers = new List<int>();
foreach(var s in words)
{
  if (int.TryParse(s, out i)) {integers.Add(i);}
}
// now you have a list of integers
// if using decimal, use decimal instead of integer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows.

```
var numbers = Console.ReadLine();
var listOfNumbers = numbers.Split(new[]{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                           .Select(x=> Int32.Parse(x));
```

The above lines split the user input based on "whitespace", removing any empty entries in between, and then converts the string numbers to integers.

The `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` ensures that empty entries are removed. An example of empty entry would be an string where two delimiters occur next to each other. For example, `"2  3 4 5"`, there are two whitespaces between 2  and 3,which means, when you are spliting the string with whitespace as delimiter, you end up with an empty element in array. This is eliminated by usage of `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Depending on whether you are expecting Integers or Decimals, you can use `Int32.Parse` or `Double.Parse` (or float/decimal etc)

Furthermore, you can include checks to ensure you have a valid number, otherwise throw an exception. You can alter the query as follows.

```
var listOfNumbers = numbers.Split(new[]{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Select(x=> 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(x);
                        if(Int32.TryParse(x,out var number))
                            return number;
                        else
                            throw new Exception("Element is not a number");
                    });
```

This ensures all the element in the list are valid numbers, otherwise throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the spaces and do the "split" using the space "data.split(' ');".